# Swift, JSON parsing not working with ÆØÅ

Tags: json, database, parsing, swift

Im trying to learn Swift and IOS development. Right now I have been struggling with a simple quiz app for a couple of days. I have got the app working, and I even managed to connect it to a database. The problem now, using JSON parsing I can parse text just fine from the database until I replace my dummy text with normal text and characters. The parsing script looks like this:

```
   let urlPath = "xxxx/json.php"
    let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlPath)!
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    var questionNummer = 0

    // let sporsmalArray=[question]()
    typealias questionArray = [AnyObject] // or whatever is inside, maybe String

    println("starting web request")
    let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in

        println("passed web request")
        if (error != nil) {
            // If there is an error in the web request, print it to the console
            println("WebError: " + error.localizedDescription)
        }else {
            println("no web request error")
            var err: NSError?
            var jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &err) as NSDictionary
            if err != nil {
                // If there is an error parsing JSON, print it to the console
                println("JSON Error \(err!.localizedDescription)")
            }
            else {
                println("no json error")
                let questions=jsonResult["data"] as? [[String:String]]
                if(questions == nil){println("questions is nil")}
                if (questions != nil) {
                    for question in questions! {
                        println("for: question")
                        questionNummer += 1
                        let answer1=question["answerOne"]!
                        let answer2=question["answerTwo"]!
                        let answer3=question["answerThree"]!
                        let answer4=question["answerFour"]!
                        let aidd=question["id"]!
                        let questionItself=question["questionTemplate"] as String!
                        let correctAnswerJson=question["correctAnswer"]
                        println("question parsed")

                        var newQuestion = [questionItself , answer1  , answer2  , answer3 , answer4, correctAnswerJson]



                        var questionArray = Array<myspecialarray>();

                        questionArray.append(newQuestion)



                        if(questionArray.isEmpty) {println("questionArray is null")}
                        else{println("questionArray is not null")}


                        self.sporsmalArray.append(questionArray)



                        println("Neste printer sporsmal arrayen:")
                        println(self.sporsmalArray)
                        println("Arrayen er ferdig")


                      //Jeg kaller på intial state her for å få med verdiene i arrayen
                        self.initialState()

                    }
                }else{
                    println("Kjører ikke")}

            }
        }
    })

    task.resume()
```

If the database contains æøå the script wont add anything to my array. My printlines show that the script works, but when im printing the array its empty.

```
starting web request
Dette teller påå spørsmålsarrayen: 0
passed web request
no web request error
no json error
questions is nil
```

When I remove the nordic letters from the database, the script works just fine again.

```
  starting web request
Dette teller påå spørsmålsarrayen: 0
passed web request
no web request error
no json error
for: question
question parsed
questionArray is not null
Neste printer sporsmal arrayen:
[(
        (
        "Dettekommerfrainternet ! ",
        as1nett,
        aa2nett,
        aa3nett,
        aa4nett,
        4
    )
)]
```

The database charset is set to varchar and swedish utf-8.

What can this problem be?

Comment: You should put your international characters back in the database and then examine the resulting JSON. It's hard to say what the problem is without seeing the actual JSON or a test URL that actually manifests the problem. I suspect a server issue, but there's not enough here to diagnose the issue.

Comment: Yes of course, I have put them back. Thanks for your time. :)

Comment: When I went into the URL in the browser, its also nil. So I think you are right regarding the server issue. Any idea what the problem can be?

Comment: I fixed it!  By putting mysqli_set_charset($con, "utf8"); after the connection in my php script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be an error with my php to Json script. 
By putting mysqli_set_charset($con, "utf8");
after the connection solved it.